# How to write this function with just min or max

Tags: python, max, min

Write the function:

`buy_house(cost, bank_acc, IRA)`

which returns the loan you would need if you can afford a downpayment on the house (1/20 its value), or 0 if you cannot afford a house given the house selling price in `cost`, amount in your bank account in `bank_acc` and the amount in your retirement account given by `IRA`. You can only use up to 35000 in your IRA account.

So far, I've got:

```
down_payment = (1/20) * cost
total_cash = back_acc + min(IRA, 35000)
```

I have no idea how to proceed and I've been at this for 3 days now. I am supposed to use just min and max to derive it, no conditionals, loops or etc. I feel so stupid being stuck on a question as easy as this.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this will be impossible without a sort of conditions. Please provide some extra information of logic so we can understand a bit better

Answer (score 0):

The critical hint is that `min` and `max` are, indeed, a sort of `if` statement.

```
def min(a, b):
    if a < b: return a
    else:     return b
```

You need to carefully plan out your computations:

- maximum IRA contribution
- maximum down payment
- loan needed

And, finally

- If the down payment is enough, return the loan amount; else, return 0.

Can you take it from there?  Note that Stack Overflow is not a coding service or tutorial site, but we can help get you over a single sticking point.  This should do it.

Comment: yeah, I think I figured it out. I had to rewrite it on paper and see the relationship lol. thanks tho eh